# php list upack string

Tags: php, php-7

[this link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.list)

says `list() can no longer unpack string variables. str_split() should be used instead.`

What does `list() upacks string` mean? Please give an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
we find:

```
<?php
$string = "abcde";
list($foo) = $string;
var_dump($foo);
// output: string(1) "a"
```

It would take apart the string variable, which can be accessed like an array, to expand into the elements specified in `list()`

In newer versions of PHP, the assignment would have to be implemented like this:

```
list($foo) = str_split($string);
```

`list()` no longer performs implicit splitting.

Comment: What I did was directly assigning the string like `list($foo) = 'abcde';` and in PHP 5.6 $foo is null.