# how to transfomr list() into str_split?

Tags: php, string, list, strsplit

I want to upgrade my server's PHP from 5.5 to 7, as I heard it will perform faster.

I read in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) that:

> list() can no longer unpack string variables. str_split() should be
>   used instead.

Currently I have a string `quantity` variable which contains a string of comma seperated numbers, like `2,5,3`.

I'm using `list` in order to create 3 new variables, one per each of these 3 comma separated values:

```
list($item[$key + 1]["red"], $item[$key + 1]["green"], $item[$key + 1]["blue"]) = explode(",", $item[$key + 1]["quantity"]);
```

Will this command no longer work on PHP 7? If so, how should I write it with `str_split`?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as you are not unpacking string variables.

Comment: There is a PHP sandbox online under [PHP-Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/). There you can test such things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php list upack string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965277/php-list-upack-string)

Answer (score 0):

You may use explode to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
$quantity = '2,5,3';
$item = explode(',',$quantity);
print_r($item);
```

Comment: I'm working with multiple arrays and using a loop. I can't fit it into a single command.

Comment: You didn't say that in your original question. Can you be more specific about what your requirements are? You should be able to take the array values after the explode and assign them as you need to.